# How can I implement paging in listview in android?

Tags: android, listview

I want to make an application in which I have 100 uri  of images that are saved in database..Now I want that whole data will not  be fetched from  database only to display in listview. I want that I get data only up to current view screen of list so next item I scroll the list than next data items will be fetched so application will not be slow for display data in listview.

Answer (score 3):

lengthy list-view doesn't make your scrolling slow
just fetch all 100 uri in single occurence and fill in adapter;
it will work properly...

Answer (score 2):

There is a scroll listener below:

```
class EndlessScrollListener implements OnScrollListener{
    private static final String TAG = "CacheToDBActivity.EndlessScrollListener";
    private boolean loading = true;

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (!(loading) && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Load Next Page!");
            loading = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}

    public boolean isLoading() {
        return loading;
    }

    public void setLoading(boolean loading) {
        this.loading = loading;
    }

}
```

You can instantiate an EndlessScrollListener and set your listview's onScrollListener like:

```
yourListView.setOnScrollListener(endlessScrollListener);
```

And above the endlessscrollListener's `Log.d(TAG, "Load Next Page!");` line you can fetch items from database, and add them to your adapter.

After calling `notifyDataSetChanged();` your items will be visible in the list

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Check out [cwac endless adapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) to implement paging.