# Android - How to show list data without scrolling

Tags: java, android

This is my application require :

- Get data from a server (JSON)

- Show all data report like image above. Data will display as multi page ( do not scroll), use next and previous button to switch

See how I want: 
 [image]

I can get data from server and show data as listview. But I have some problem and need help.

**1.** How to display data like image I attached. I found some way but seem it is not good 

**2.** How to display data as multi page. I do not know exactly how much data because it depend data on Server, i have to show all data on server. Pages should auto generate depend on data.

Thanks you.

Comment: use `TableView` to meet your requirement

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553437/how-can-i-implement-paging-in-listview-in-android). And one more thing, **this is not an *default Android Behavior*, So Please do not follow this design.** Better to use *Load More* Functionality :)

Comment: @SweetWisherツ Can you suggest me another design to show the report ? Thanks

Comment: [Load more list view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458475/android-listview-to-load-more-items-when-reached-end)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do it would be to create three datasets (let's say arraylists) and keep previous page data in one and current and future in the next one.
Then put an onClickListener that changes the data in listviews and then notify adapter using .notifyDatasetChanged().

Comment: @SweetWisherツ Can you suggest a better way ? I will appreciate your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an **default Android Behavior**, So Please do not follow this design. Better to use *Load More Functionality* :)

[image]

 You can refer links for that.

- [ListView to load more items when reached to an end](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20458604/2591002)
- [LoadMore library](https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore)
- [Infinite Scroll ListView](https://github.com/weixiao1984/Android-Infinite-Scroll-Listview)